# How to get degrees with certain edge labels using python

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, directed-graph

[image: Directed graph with labeled edges]

I would like to find the node degree with edges of certain labels, when I use the  the degree() method of networkx it gives me a dic with {:} but how to get the labels of those edges?. Any help including the info on what other graph analysis packages has this provision, is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have tried? :)

Answer (score 1):

In igraph, you want `g.es.select(_source=i)`.  This gets all of the edges whose source vertex is i, at which point you can ask for the attributes of those edges:

```
>>> g = igraph.Graph.Full(3) #complete graph on three vertices
>>> g.es['label'] = ['a','b','c'] #sets the first edge to have 'label' value 'a', etc.
>>> g.es.select(_source=0)['label']
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

## Nodes' degree by certain edges labels

### Random graph functions

```
def rand_gen(m):
    yield random.randint(0,m)

def get_edges(n):
    tpl = []
    for _ in range(n):
        for x,y in zip(rand_gen(n), rand_gen(n)):
            tpl.append((x,y, {random.choice(['a','b','c']): random.randint(0,10)}))
    return tpl
```

### Create graph

```
g = nx.Graph()

e = get_edges(10)

g.add_edges_from(e)

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,pos, font_color='w')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos, edge_labels={(x,y):l.keys()[0] for x,y,l in g.edges(data=True)})
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Select by label

```
nds = []
nds.extend([n1, n2] for n1,n2,l in g.edges(data=True) if l.keys()[0] == 'a')
nds = [x for y in nds for x in y]
```

### Get the degree of unique labels

```
[nx.degree(g,x) for x in set(nds)]
```

[out]

```
[2, 3, 2, 2, 5]
```